# Choppy/Slow Animation on first load cocos2d

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

Write now, I'm creating an interactive ebook using cocos2d.  When the program runs the cover page animation is choppy only on initial load.  This animation is on the cover page and it is huge.  We're talking 13 texture atlases, 26 images.

I know the problem stems from preloading/loading images, but I already loaded all the images before the animation occurs.

```
-(id) init {
     if( (self=[super init]) ) {
               isTouchEnabled_=YES;
    //Pg0 Animations
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"CB0A0.plist"];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"CB0A1.plist"];
    ...etc.}}
```

The overall set up of the book is as follows. I build a scene, a menu layer, and then the menu layer pushes and pops different layers/ different pages.

When the cover page is loaded (Pg0), if the user touches a picture it runs through the animation.  Then when the user, touches the picture again, a second animation runs.

All the images of the book are loaded in the menu layer (so before any page pushes or pops).  I've tried loading these images on the scene, or the individual pages to speed up the process, but that doesn't affect time.

I am running my animation through an animation helper, which loops through the images for me.

Any help would be wonderful, and I am would love to share more code or info about the project if it needed.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong!!!  If you have an animation that uses images from two different texture files, then there will be a pause to load in the new textures assuming you haven't already preloaded the specific texture.  Just writing a line of code such as `[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"yourTexture.plist"];` will not load the texture cache.  You have to call a specific image of the cache your animation is in and add it to the layer.  For this I simply added a sprite of all animation textures and made them invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your AppDelegate implements the memory warning method. Check what that method does.

By default, cocos2d implements that method and purges all caches. Now when that gets triggered while preloading textures, what happens is that cocos2d removes the preloaded textures because a memory warning was received yet those preloaded textures aren't in use yet. Cocos2d considers them to be "unused" and removes them from memory. Which means next time you use that texture, it needs to be loaded from disk again.

I wrote a blog post [where I describe this issue, and ways to solve it](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/). Most importantly: get TexturePacker and use only .pvr.ccz for texture atlases. Try to reduce texture color depth to 16 bit where possible. And be sure to dump texture memory usage to learn how much memory you're actually using, and whether that amount of memory is within reasonable limits. Including older devices with fewer memory that you may be supporting.

Comment: I've actually followed your book on most of the optimizations (yay) - 16bit, texture packer, .pvr.ccz, etc. However, I didn't know about the texture compression, which I'll definitely implement, but from what I've read your blog post describes the best practices so far.  Will keep this updated if I find anything else.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. When use cocos2d v0.9 animation was ok, no lag. Lag appears when migrating to cocos2d v2.0.

When you add sprites to cache (addSpriteFramesWithFile:(NSString*)plist) in cocos2d v0.9 texture2d is also created (CCSpriteFrameCache.m:238), in cocos2d v2.0 there is no textture2d creation, texture is created at first use of CCSpriteFrame. I fix it by adding

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:textureFileName];
```

in CCSpriteFrameCache.m:207 (v2.0)

Answer (score 1):

I was just experiencing this problem in cocos2D v3.1 iphone. I had spritesheets that were cached but still were stuttering on loading. I found somewhere on another post that you need to load the texture itself as well to get rid of the initial lag. This is what I did in my caching sprites method:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"spritesheet.plist"];
CCTexture *temporaryLoadTexture = [CCTexture textureWithFile:@"spritesheet.png"];
```

Just by loading a dummy CCTexture file, that got rid of all first-time animation and sprite lag. Hope this helps!